# Rewriting a for loop into multiprocess.Pool().map

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to achieve what this for loop does only with the `multiprocessing.Pool().map` function.

```
# for loop
List = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
numbers = range(5)
for i in numbers:
    List[i] = 1
print(List)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

When I try to map these numbers for `multiprocessing`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial


def function(numbers, List):
    List[numbers] = 1
    return List

def function_pool(numbers, List):
    func_part = partial(function, List=List)
    result = mp.Pool().map(func_part, numbers)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # pool function
    List = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    numbers = range(5)
    result = function_pool(numbers, List)
    print(result)
```

the output is:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Do I have to slice the list afterwards outside the pool or is there a built in method for doing this?

Comment: Each process created by the pool receives a copy of the program state, so each one modifies its own copy of `List` and then returns the modified list. You shouldn't usually use `Pool.map` to directly assign values, but to compute the values that are assigned to the result list. So here you would have `def function(n): return 1` and then `result = mp.Pool().map(function, numbers)`, then `result` would have the list you expect.

Comment: To actually share memory between spawned processes, see [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), and in Python 3.8 there is also [`multiprocessing.shared_memory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html).

Comment: @jdehesa your first comment was enough solution for my code to work. Thank you :-)